# JComboBox Help to delete data from database

Tags: java, database, jcombobox

I have a table in database `employee` composed by two columns *ID* and *NameLastName*.

I arrived to add data in the second column to a JComboBox like in the snapshot down!

[image]

Now how can I do to delete the selected employee in the JComboBox from DB?

I thought to add the ID with name like this `I122-Name` and use split method to extract the ID but I don't want to show the ID.

Is there any way to associate with each name in the JComboBox a hidden value that contains the employee ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to show the ID.

This question has already received 2 good answers, but I wanted to add this 3rd one if only to address the question of whether to show the ID (which was not part of the question, but should have been).

### Screen Shot

Which *John Smith* are you going to fire?

[image]

### SackEmployee.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class SackEmployee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Employee[] workforce = {
                    new Employee("Ali Ben Messaoud", 9823),
                    new Employee("Jane Brewer", 6348),
                    new Employee("John Smith", 1247),
                    new Employee("John Smith", 4385)
                };

                JComboBox employeeCombo = new JComboBox(workforce);

                EmployeeCellRenderer employeeCellRenderer = new EmployeeCellRenderer();
                employeeCombo.setRenderer(employeeCellRenderer);

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                    null,
                    employeeCombo,
                    "Fire Employee?",
                    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
                // cast selected item back to Employee.
                Employee employee = (Employee)employeeCombo.getSelectedItem();
                System.out.println( "Fire '" + employee + "' now?" );
                System.out.println( "Proceed: " + (result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) );
            }
        });
    }
}

class Employee {

    int id;
    String name;

    Employee(String name, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIdString() {
        return "ID-" + id;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getIdString() + ": " + name;
    }
}

class EmployeeCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(
        JList list,
        Object value,
        int index,
        boolean isSelected,
        boolean cellHasFocus) {

        Employee employee = (Employee)value;
        // distinguish between people of same name by adding ID.
        label.setText(employee.name + " (" + employee.getIdString() + ")");

        return label;
    }
}
```

### E.G. I/O

```
prompt>java SackEmployee
Fire 'ID-9823: Ali Ben Messaoud' now?
Proceed: false

prompt>java SackEmployee
Fire 'ID-1247: John Smith' now?
Proceed: true

prompt>java SackEmployee
Fire 'ID-4385: John Smith' now?
Proceed: false

prompt>
```

Comment: Is that 'in advance' in terms of not having 'fired' you?  ;)

Comment: For both! And sure for answer! ;)

Answer (score 4):

- Create an Employee object that has both fields.
- Override the toString() method to output the employee name.
- Put the Employee objects in the JComboBox and the name will be displayed but you can cast the selected object to an Employee and pull out the id.

Comment: public String toString(){ return name;}

Comment: Just a simple two variable Employee object.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

Make an Employee class with field name and id then make a class which implements `ListCellRenderer` and extends `JLabel`. Add this class as a Renderer to your JComboBox. Now you can set Name as a text in JLabel. <del>Now when ever you access comboBox's element it will return you JLabel and you can get name as visible value and id as hidden value from where you have set in JLabel.</del>

JComboBox's method `getSelectedItem()` returns an Object that can be cast to whatever Object was placed in the combobox. To get the component used to render the items, call `getRenderer()`.

Note:- You can use other component then JLabel.

---

A demo:-

```
public class ComboRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        if(value != null){
            Employee emp = (Employee) value;
            setText(emp.getName());
            return this;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now where you want to add item to comboBox use `combo.addItem(empObject);`. It will display name of employee in comboBox and when you do `getSelectedItem()` it will return you the employee object and you will get name and id both belongs to that emp object.

Comment: @Andrew: I tried to explain the thing using an example. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

here is simple code that will delete entire row in database.

```
    try{
      String str;
      con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://:3306/database","user","password");
      stat = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT column_name FROM table_name where column_name = '"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString()+"';");
      while(rs.next()){
         Str = rs.getString(column_name);
      }
      stat.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM table_name where column_name = +"str"+");
    }
    rs.close();
    stat.close();
    con.close();
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println(e);
    }
```